# Selenium + ChromeDriver + Headless Chrome - failed to wait for extension background page to load

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java, chromedriver

I am using Selenium 3.10.0 + ChromeDriver 2.37.543619 + Google Chrome 65.0.3325.162

I have a browser extension that I need when testing:

[Browser extension](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/attachment?aid=330118&signed_aid=RkWFIDa8dBw0LLG860Kldg==)

I am running this code:

```
  ChromeDriver webDriver = null;
  System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", new File("chromedriver").getAbsolutePath());
  System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.logfile", "chromedriver.log");
  System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.verboseLogging", "true");
  ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
  chromeOptions.addArguments("--enable-logging", "--v=1", "--disable-sand-box");
  chromeOptions.setHeadless(true);
  chromeOptions.addExtensions(new File("/home/ndipiazza/Downloads/chrome-request-counter.crx"));
  webDriver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Starting ChromeDriver 2.37.543619 (a237acd3116cac3b3f0da42a000502ce3fafcb23) on port 6679
Only local connections are allowed.
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: failed to wait for extension background page to load: chrome-extension://nehbkkpdaccfofjkopcgnlhhgfoabbnc/_generated_background_page.html
from unknown error: page could not be found: chrome-extension://nehbkkpdaccfofjkopcgnlhhgfoabbnc/_generated_background_page.html
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.37.543619 (a237acd3116cac3b3f0da42a000502ce3fafcb23),platform=Linux 4.13.0-37-generic x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 10.27 seconds
Build info: version: '3.10.0', revision: '176b4a9', time: '2018-03-02T19:03:16.397Z'
System info: host: 'mate', ip: '127.0.0.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.13.0-37-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_141'
```

**This works totally fine when using non-headless chrome.**

Looks like a bug so I opened a bug [here is the bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=2342)

Is there a workaround anyone knows of for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Oh blah!

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45372066/is-it-possible-to-run-google-chrome-in-headless-mode-with-extensions/45372648#45372648

Firefox supports headless extensions but not google chrome. :(

Answer (score 2):

**No**, *Google Chrome* in *headless* mode doesn't supports extensions.

In the one of his [comment](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=604324#c57), `@alexclarke@chromium.org` clearly mentioned:

> I realize a lot of folks would like to use extensions with headless but unfortunately that's a large project which we have /no plans to do/.  The problem is Headless Chromium is a content embedder which means it doesn't have access to anything from other content embedders such as chrome and unfortunately extensions are a chrome feature.

In another [comment](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=604324#c54) he further added, if you're using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) through [DevTools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59420493/how-to-use-chrome-devtools-protocol-in-selenium-using-python-for-capturing-htt/59424003#59424003) you can build a proxy. You can filter URLs and modify headers via [Network.setRequestInterception](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Network/#method-setRequestInterception)  and [Network.continueInterceptedRequest](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Network/#method-continueInterceptedRequest).

Comment: +1 for the info about proxy